# AEM 6.1 missing CQ javascript function

Tags: jquery, aem

I am getting the following error:

```
VM13430 editor.js:25678Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shared' of undefined
```

When loading a page in author mode in AEM 6.1 in the Granite UI.  It is failing at the following line:

```
var isLockOwner = true;
    if(info.status.isLocked){
        isLockOwner = ns.ContentFrame && ns.ContentFrame.contentWindow.CQ.shared.User.data.userID === info.status.lockOwner;
    }
```

And in debugging `ns.ContentFrame.contentWindow.CQ`, 'CQ' is missing.
On checking the Geometrixx demo content, 'CQ' is a function, and I assume is the jQuery resolution for the jquery.

As a result, I am unable to unlock the page if locked.  Although I can unlock the page if in the page grid view.

How do I ensure I can CQ is loaded for 'ns.ContentFrame.contentWindow'?

Comment: what clientlibs do you load? What relations do thay have. Do you by accident do any "embed" in your clientlibs?

Comment: @ub1k, Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction.  On inspecting the demo Geometrixx site, it appears I am missing 'embed'.

Answer (score 2):

In the `.content.xml` in the clientlibs directory add the following:

`embed="[underscore,granite.shared,cq.shared,jquery.jcarousel,cq.foundation,cq.foundation-main,jquery-ui,cq.jquery.ui,personalization,personalization.core,personalization.core.kernel,personalization.clientcontext.kernel,personalization.stores.kernel,personalization.kernel,personalization.clientcontext,personalization.stores,cq.social.tagging,cq.ckeditor,cq.social.scf,cq.social.author.hbs.message,cq.social.author.hbs.messagebox,cq.social.author.hbs.composemessage,cq.social.author.hbs.userchooser,cq.social.author.hbs.comments,cq.social.author.hbs.forum,cq.social.author.hbs.journal,cq.social.author.hbs.rating,cq.social.author.hbs.qna,cq.social.author.hbs.voting,cq.social.author.hbs.reviews,cq.social.author.hbs.search,cq.social.author.hbs.calendar,cq.social.hbs.socialgraph,cq.social.calendar,cq.social.calendar.eventbasics,cq.social.calendar.fullcalendar,cq.social.author.hbs.socialgraph.following,cq.social.author.hbs.activitystreams,cq.social.commons.infiniscroll]"`

Comment: I hate that adobe is hiding everything. Your answer is amazing. Every javascript Object from adobe is working now. Never expect that. Thank you

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought it helped, but it was just the chrome browser in the devolper mode. I still don't reach the CQ Object in my javascript files

Answer (score 2):

basically the issue here is that you need to include a clientLib - cq.shared

According to Adobe : 
"
  The editor client library assumes the presence of the cq.shared namespace 
  in content pages, and if it is absent the JavaScript error Uncaught 
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'shared' of undefined will result.

All sample content pages contain cq.shared, so any content based on them automatically includes cq.shared. However, if you decide to create your own content pages from scratch without basing them on sample content, you must make sure to include the cq.shared namespace.
"

for some reason the embed did not work for me, however calling the clientLib from the base html seemed to work

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" />
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='cq.shared'}"/>
```

Comment: a little addition, the embed did not work but after a bit more time spent on it, 
adding
dependencies="cq.shared" worked